# How do you get a sublist of elements in fixed order in Python? What about with fillers?

Tags: python, list, nlp

If I have a list of strings from a tokenized string, how do I get a sublist from the list starting at a phrase (a fixed-order list of strings, not just one string, although `len(phrase)` could be 1 or more) and ending at another phrase (again, 1 or more)?

How do you extend the above so that it works with fillers, like `start_phrase = ["I", "don't", "think", "FILLER", "would", "appreciate"]`?

Here's a pseudo-example of input and expected output:

```py
lst = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("This is a sentence.\
    Do you prefer sentences that are short, or sentences that are long?")
lst.sublist(["Do", "you", "prefer", "FILLER", "that"], ["or"])
```

```sh
["are", "short", ","]
```

N.B. that word_tokenize() doesn't only have "words" in the list it returns, but also punctuation, like so: `","`.

Comment: What is the input and the expected output?